# Working with PostgreSQL information_schema and tables (with same names, in different schemas) whose names start with a number

Tags: postgresql-9.3, datatypes, information-schema

I'm needing to work with tables whose names start with numbers. For example, in the `crs_1973` schema there is a table called `2015_04_21`. I know that when the table name is made up of numbers, I must double quote it to work with it, for example, `SELECT * FROM crs_1973."2015_04_21";` (this works for me). However, I want to extract information about this table from the PostgreSQL `information_schema`. Specifically, I need the data types of the columns in the table `2015_04_21`,

I have tried this query with a table whose name starts with a letter and it produces the desired result:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'some_table_name_that_starts_with_a_letter'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position;
```

However, when I run this query with the tables whose names begin with a number, it does not. For example:

```
WHERE  table_name = 'crs_1973.2015_04_21'
```

does not work. Nor does:

```
WHERE  table_name = 'crs_1973'.'2015_04_21'
WHERE  table_name = 'crs_1973'."2015_04_21"
WHERE  table_name = 'crs_1973'.'"2015_04_21"'
...
```

etc. How do I make this query work for a table name that starts with a number? Is this possible?

There are tables called "2015_04_21" in several different schemas so I need to pass a qualified table name to the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ypercube's solution (in the comments above):

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'crs_1973' AND
table_name = '2015_04_21'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position;
```

worked perfectly. I'm writing it up here so that I can accept the answer.